# How to make a virtual keyboard in C++ (or does something exist with this functionality)

Tags: emacs

So I'm not talking about a GUI application that brings up a keyboard.

But a program that remaps the input data taken from the keyboard to a unique virtual key that I can further customize.

The reason I want to make this is because <strike>Emacs (a programmable text editor) and</strike> the terminal reserve(s) a few very valuable keystrokes (In my opinion, of course). For example: <kbd>C-i</kbd> and <kbd>C-m</kbd>.

Instead I want to have a clean slate where I don't have to use certain hacks to get around these very annoying restrictions.

Comment: If you're using X windows, it allows remapping keys with `xmodmap`. Emacs doesn't reserve keys, you can modify them to you heart's content in your `.emacs` file.

Comment: Awe interesting.
So, to clarify, I can finally get rid of the terminal using C-i as tab using xmodmap?

Comment: I don't think so. `xmodmap` operates at a lower level than that, it maps keys to X key codes. Equating TAB and C-i is done in the applications, like Emacs and terminal emulators.

Comment: The terminal emulator is emulating a terminal, which is an ancient piece of hardware that didn't distinguish `C-i` and `TAB`.  Thus aliasing `C-i` and `TAB` is correct operation for a terminal emulator.  Any programs you run inside of a terminal emulator also expect that.
  Although you can do custom workarounds for specific combinations of terminal emulators and terminal programs, I don't think you're going to find a general solution to this.

Comment: This is so stupid. I would say for 99% of the population `C-i` isn't relevant anymore, and just a stupid annoyance.